# Change order of pages when using pdfpages, Part II

Tags: pdfpages

First: This is a follow-up question to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365496/change-order-of-pages-when-using-pdfpages).

Consider the following example.

**File: `f1.tex`**

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  landscape,
  danish
]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  a6paper,
  margin = 0.8cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newenvironment{navn}{%
  \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
  \centering
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  \nointerlineskip
  \fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont
  % \sbox0{Forside}%
  % \showthe\ht0
}{%
  \par
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  % \setlength{\showboxdepth}{\maxdimen}%
  % \setlength{\showboxbreadth}{\maxdimen}%
  % \tracingonline=1 %
  % \showlists
}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=T1}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\multido{\i = 1+1}{18}{%
\begin{navn}
  Front
\end{navn}
\newpage}

\end{document}
```

**File: `f2.tex`**

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  landscape,
  danish
]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  a6paper,
  margin = 1.2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newenvironment{navn}{%
  \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
  \centering
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  \nointerlineskip
  \LARGE
  % \sbox0{XYZ}%
  % \showthe\ht0
}{%
  \par
  \vspace{\fill}%
  % \setlength{\showboxdepth}{\maxdimen}%
  % \setlength{\showboxbreadth}{\maxdimen}%
  % \tracingonline=1 %
  % \showlists
}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=T1}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{navn}
  A\\[\baselineskip]
  B
\end{navn}
\newpage

\begin{navn}
  C\\[\baselineskip]
  D
\end{navn}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

**File: `f3.tex`**

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper
]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcount\maxpages
\newcount\curpage
\newcount\untilpage
\makeatletter
\newif\if@pdfdingsunbalance
\newcount\@testmaxpages
\newcommand{\@incpdfdings}[3]{%
  \includepdf[
    nup = 3x6,
    pages = {#1-#2},
    frame = true
  ]{#3}}
\newcommand{\incpdfdings}[3][]{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \pdfximage{#2}%
        \maxpages=\pdflastximagepages%
        \pdfximage{#3}%
        \@testmaxpages=\pdflastximagepages%
        \ifnum\maxpages<\@testmaxpages%
            \@pdfdingsunbalancetrue%
            \def\@pdfdingsmore{#3}%
        \else\ifnum\@testmaxpages<\maxpages%
            \@pdfdingsunbalancetrue%
            \def\@pdfdingsmore{#2}%
            \maxpages=\@testmaxpages%
        \fi\fi%
    \else%
        \maxpages=#1%
    \fi%
    \curpage=0%
    \loop\ifnum\maxpages>\curpage%
        \advance\curpage by 1%
        \untilpage=\numexpr\curpage+17\relax%
        \ifnum\maxpages>\untilpage\else%
            \untilpage=\maxpages%
        \fi%
        \@incpdfdings{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#2}%
        \@incpdfdings{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#3}%
        \advance\curpage by 17%
    \repeat%
    \if@pdfdingsunbalance%
        \advance\maxpages by 1%
        \@incpdfdings{\the\maxpages}{}{\@pdfdingsmore}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\incpdfdings%
{f1.pdf}%
{f2.pdf}
```

With the following example compiled, it produces three pages in `f3.pdf`; it puts 18 pages from `f1.pdf` on the third page in `f3.pdf` and then moves each page from the third page to the first page whenever a new page from `f2.pdf` is put on the second page in `f3.pdf`.

**Question**

How do I move 18 pages from `f1.pdf` to the front of the assembled document in `f3.pdf` right from the beginning, then 18 pages from `f2.pdf`, then another 18 pages from `f1.pdf` and so on?

That is, I would like to have the same as with [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) but with the pages in `f3.pdf` altered between the outputs from `f1.pdf` and `f2.pdf`.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you just use `\includepdf` in that case?

Comment: My code from the original question checked, whether both documents have the same amount of pages. Since originally your question was asking for alternating f1 and f2 on one page, I thought it was logically the correct behaviour to print the number of pages both have and then the rest of the file with more pages. I'll try some stuff...

Comment: Also: In the current case, `f2` has only 2 pages. What should happen in this case? 18 pages of `f1` then 2 from `f2` and then 18 from `f1`? If `f1` has more than 36 pages should there be an empty page in `f3` for the missing pages of `f2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `f3.tex` should do what you want (I hope):

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper
]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcount\firstmaxpages
\newcount\secondmaxpages
\newcount\curpage
\newcount\untilpage
\makeatletter
\newif\if@pdfdingsSecondFin
\newcommand{\@incpdfdings}[4][]{%
    \includepdf[%
        nup = 3x6,
        pages = {#2-#3},
        #1
    ]{#4}}
\newcommand{\incpdfdings}[3][]{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \pdfximage{#2}%
        \firstmaxpages=\pdflastximagepages%
        \pdfximage{#3}%
        \secondmaxpages=\pdflastximagepages%
        \ifnum\firstmaxpages<\secondmaxpages%
            \@latex@error{incpdfdings: Second file has more pages than first}{}
        \fi%
    \else%
        \firstmaxpages=#1%
    \fi%
    \curpage=0%
    \loop\ifnum\firstmaxpages>\curpage%
        \advance\curpage by 1%
        \untilpage=\numexpr\curpage+17\relax%
        \ifnum\untilpage>\firstmaxpages%
            \untilpage=\firstmaxpages%
        \fi%
        \@incpdfdings[frame=true]{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#2}%
        \ifnum\secondmaxpages>\untilpage\else%
            \untilpage=\secondmaxpages%
        \fi%
        \if@pdfdingsSecondFin\else%
            \@incpdfdings{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#3}%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\secondmaxpages=\untilpage%
            \@pdfdingsSecondFintrue%
        \fi%
        \advance\curpage by 17%
    \repeat%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\incpdfdings%
{f1.pdf}%
{f2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: For the 2x4 pages:

- Change in the definition of `\@incpdfdings`: `nup = 3x6` to `nup =
  2x4`
- In the definition of `\incpdfdings`: Change all (2) occurences of the
  number `17` to `7`

EDIT2: I changed everything a bit, so you don't have to change anything for different options for `nup` as long as they follow the `<num>x<num>` scheme:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper
]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcount\firstmaxpages
\newcount\secondmaxpages
\newcount\curpage
\newcount\untilpage
\makeatletter
\newif\if@pdfdingsSecondFin
\newcount\@pdfdingsPages
\newcommand{\@incpdfdings}[5][]{%
    \includepdf[%
        nup = #5,
        pages = {#2-#3},
        #1
    ]{#4}}
\newcommand{\@@incpdfdings}{}%
\def\@@incpdfdings#1x#2;{%
    \@pdfdingsPages=#1%
    \multiply\@pdfdingsPages by #2%
    \advance\@pdfdingsPages by -1%
}
\newcommand{\incpdfdings}[4][]{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \pdfximage{#3}%
        \firstmaxpages=\pdflastximagepages%
        \pdfximage{#4}%
        \secondmaxpages=\pdflastximagepages%
        \ifnum\firstmaxpages<\secondmaxpages%
            \@latex@error{incpdfdings: Second file has more pages than first}{}%
        \fi%
    \else%
        \firstmaxpages=#1%
    \fi%
    \curpage=0%
    \@@incpdfdings#2;%
    \loop\ifnum\firstmaxpages>\curpage%
        \advance\curpage by 1%
        \untilpage=\numexpr\curpage+\@pdfdingsPages\relax%
        \ifnum\untilpage>\firstmaxpages%
            \untilpage=\firstmaxpages%
        \fi%
        \@incpdfdings[frame=true]{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#3}{#2}%
        \ifnum\secondmaxpages>\untilpage\else%
            \untilpage=\secondmaxpages%
        \fi%
        \if@pdfdingsSecondFin\else%
            \@incpdfdings{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#4}{#2}%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\secondmaxpages=\untilpage%
            \@pdfdingsSecondFintrue%
        \fi%
        \advance\curpage by \@pdfdingsPages%
    \repeat%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\incpdfdings{3x6}%
{f1.pdf}%
{f2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Now the command takes an additional argument specifying the `nup` option.